# Test in Mocha failing

Tags: nodejs, mocha

I am getting the following error on running the test.

**npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE**

**npm ERR! errno 1**

**npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: mocha**

**npm ERR! Exit status 1**

**npm ERR!**

**npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.**

**npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.**

I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Any ideas?

**Background**: I copied the directory of a previous project and made the necessary changes including a new .sol file and a new .js file for writing the tests.
I have already tried recopying all the node modules and I have also reinstalled mocha.

Comment: Hi there. Please ask this question on the main Stack Overflow site. It's not specifically related to Ethereum.

Comment: Do you have more log output?

Comment: Yes I there is a log file and also more of the error message in the terminal itself when I run the test. However the contents are too long to post as a comment.
Would it help if I post the link to the GitHub repo?

Comment: If it is too long you can put the result in pastebin or a github gist. But ask in StackOverflow.com if it is not related to ethereum.

Comment: Hi, I understand this question is off topic. I want to delete it but I am getting a warning asking me not to delete an answered question. Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem in the past, did you **install** node, mocha or web3 **as root**?

**Installing as root**, will not let you use them as you want to do here because as you install as root, **the files get installed out of the project folder** with different permissions than usual applications.
So to solve that:

- Erease the node_modules folder
- Re-install all the packages:

  apt-get install nodejs@lastest
  apt-get install npm@lastest
  apt-get install web3@"version you want to use"
- Then if the problem persists, look wich libraries are missing and install them (You can see them because they should appear before the message you show of mocha on the Console).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! No I did not install the packages globally. I had installed all the packages locally in the previous project. I think the issue is occurring because I copied the previous project folder.

Comment: Nope, i've done that lots of times, and if all works fine on the first folder, keepg going well on the next ones.

The type of error you are having as I told you, probably comes from installing as root the packages. Try installing it not as root.

Comment: It worked for me, while installing as root, causes dependencies to don't be accessible for the other installations/packages.